# Non-Unicode to unicode conversion of a txt file

Tags: c#, unicode, non-unicode

Given a txt file with non-unicode text, I am able to detect its charset as **1251**. Now, I would like to convert into unicode.

```
byte[] bytes1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(File.ReadAllText("sampleNU.txt"));
String str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes1251);
```

This doesn't work.

Is this the way to go about it for **non-unicode to unicode conversion**?

After trying the suggested approach on the RTF file, I get the below dialog when I try to open the output RTF file. Please let me know what to do because selecting Unicode doesn't make it readable or give the expected text?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
// load as charset 1251
string text = File.ReadAllText("sampleNU.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));

// save as Unicode
File.WriteAllText("sampleU.txt", text, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! When I try your code with RTF file, I get the attached dialog. Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: @Holly - rtf ([rich text format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)) is not txt (plain text). What you really want to do?

Comment: @Holly: You should also say what's creating that dialog - we don't know what application is trying to open the file.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Sorry, I have mentioned txt file earlier. It needs to convert rtf non-unicode to rtf unicode.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you Jon! MS Word creates that dialog when I open the output rtf file.

Comment: @Holly: Okay, so if you specify that it's Unicode in the dialog box, does it then do the right thing? That would at least suggest the text has been converted properly. I don't know what rules Word uses to determine whether or not to show the dialog...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you Jon! The dialog has the bottom section that shows the preview of the text. That's the output like. Not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @Holly: Well that looks like valid RTF to me. It's not clear what you'd expect it to be.